# File.Delete isn't working to delete image from sub folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

In our ASP.NET program a user can upload an image to a folder. The location of the image (including the name of the upload folder which is in the root directory) is stored as a variable called "path", ie. "Uploads/fileName.jpg".

To remove the image:

```
if (File.Exists("~/" + path))
                {
                    File.Delete("~/" + path);
                }
```

However, it fails to run because it can't verify that the file exists. Through some testing we noticed it's looking for "path" in the "system32" directory. Why would this be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use Server.Map path to ensure that the Tilde is resolved correctly.

MSDN Article is here -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632(v=vs.90).aspx

Your code would become

```
var fixedPath = Server.MapPath("~/" + path);

if (File.Exists(fixedPath))
{
  File.Delete(fixedPath);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I posted a fix rather than answering your question!  The reason why system32 is searched not the expected folder, is that IIS runs from that folder.  So it bases itself from the executing folder not the expected publish/project folder.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the solution! I tried the code you suggested, but the image still isn't being deleted, any other thoughts?

Comment: Oh okay, that makes total sense. Thanks for the edit!

Comment: Put a break point and inspect the value of the fixedPath, it should look correct.

Answer (score 3):

The `File` class is not aware of the IIS directory mapping, so it won't understand `~` correctly. You have to first use a method to map the app relative path to a local path with `Server.MapPath`